# Как проверить в массиве есть ли значение

Tags: php

У меня есть вложенный массив:

```
  ["items"]=> 
  {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["property"]=> "Promo"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["property"]=> "Sale"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(4) {
      ["property"]=> "Not exist"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(4) {
      ["property"]=> "New"
    }
```

Как мне проверить есть ли вложенных массивах элемент именно со значением 'Promo' ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4128323/7791165

Comment: @Kek array_walk_recursive() в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

видимо как то так

```
$exists = in_array("Promo", array_column($data['items'], "property"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте array_walk_recursive():

```
$arr = [
    "items"=> [
        ["property" => "Promo"],
        ["property" => "Sale"],
        ["property" => "Not exist"],
        ["property" => "New"]
    ]
];

const PROMO = 'Promo';

array_walk_recursive($arr, function($item, $key){
    PROMO != $item ?: print $item;
});
```